# IBM x3200 M3 - RAM compatibility

Tags: memory, hardware, ibm-xseries

I've got my hands on a IBM x3200 M3 server.

ESXi 5.1 is installed on it and more RAM would be much needed since there's only 2 GB installed for the moment.

Does anyone know how it's working with RAM modules for hardware like this.
I know the manual say that there are certified modules that works with the hardware and there's nothing strange with that.

The question is, would "any" other DDR3 ECC modules work?

Comment: Please google abit more before you ask.  http://serverfault.com/questions/323685/ibm-server-ram-vs-other-server-ram. In other works, yes it works, but no support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your questions is *maybe*. It depends on the spec's of the memory, if the memory matches the specification then there is no reason why it will not work.

---

Your system supports the following memory -

Registered ECC (RDIMMs):

- Up to six single-rank RDIMMs for a maximum of 6 GB (6x 1 GB)
- Up to six dual-rank RDIMMs for a maximum of 24 GB (6x 4 GB)
- Up to six quad-rank RDIMMs for a maximum of 48 GB (6x 8 GB)

ECC Unbuffered (UDIMMs):

- Up to four single-rank UDIMMs for a maximum of 4 GB (4x 1 GB)
- Up to four dual-rank UDIMMs for a maximum of 16 GB (4x 4 GB)

---

In short, max is 48GB with Registered ECC memory (RDIMM) and 16GB with ECC unbuffered memory (UDIMM). It has 6 slots. Supported speeds are PC3-8500(1066MHz), PC3-10600 (1333MHz). 2GB is the minimum RAM requirement for ESXi 5.1, however 8GB is recommended. IMO, you should look for anything above 8GB.

Note: *Registered ECC memory is supported only by systems* with **Intel Xeon 3400 Series** processors, so make sure what type of processor you have before purchasing the memory.

Hope that answers your question!!

*Source* - http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/tips0802.html

Comment: Is it common that the chipset **require** specific ranks of modules, or is it more for what, in this case IBM, _like to support_?